# Pan an Image with Left Click: Rate of Scroll is faster than Mouse (.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, autoscroll, pan, panning

The goal is to pan a form or image on the form when left clicking, and dragging the mouse.  The below code works perfectly fine for my needs, but there is only one issue.  When I left click and drag the mouse, the form pans quicker than the mouse, making it awkward.  Is there any method I can use to make the form pan *at the same rate* as my mouse?  Here is my code:

```
Private leftClick as Point

Private Sub Form_OnMouseDown(sender as Object, e as MouseEventArgs) Handles Form.MouseDown
    leftClick = e.Position
End Sub

Private Sub Form_OnMouseMove(sender as Object, e as MouseEventArgs) Handles Form.MouseMove
    'Resolves issue where mouse keeps on moving even if not
    Static MyPoint As New Point
    If e.Location = MyPoint Then Exit Sub
    MyPoint = e.Location

    'If we left click anywhere on form, pan the form
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim DeltaX As Integer = (leftClick.X - e.x) 
        Dim DeltaY As Integer = (leftClick.Y - e.y) 

        Dim newX as Integer = DeltaX - Me.AutoScrollPosition.X
        Dim newY as Integer = DeltaY - Me.AutoScrollPosition.Y

        'Then we set the new autoscroll position.
        Me.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(newX, newY)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are basing the scroll directly on the mouse move.  Just scale it down to scroll less (change your calc for Delta)

Comment: Right, I can scale it down, but how would I scale it so that it matches the rate of my mouse movement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a little mistake in your code:

```
Private Sub Form_OnMouseMove(sender as Object, e as MouseEventArgs) Handles Form.MouseMove
    'Resolves issue where mouse keeps on moving even if not
    Static MyPoint As New Point
    If e.Location = MyPoint Then Exit Sub
    MyPoint = e.Location

    'If we left click anywhere on form, pan the form
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim DeltaX As Integer = (leftClick.X - e.x) 
        Dim DeltaY As Integer = (leftClick.Y - e.y) 

        Dim newX as Integer = DeltaX - Me.AutoScrollPosition.X
        Dim newY as Integer = DeltaY - Me.AutoScrollPosition.Y

        'Then we set the new autoscroll position.
        Me.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(newX, newY)

        'Add this code
        leftClick.X = e.X '<---
        leftClick.Y = e.Y '<---
    End If
End Sub
```

You need the difference between the previous mouse position and the current one. What you did was to calculate the total from the position you clicked.

Comment: Thank you for helping me track down my coding oversight.